# How to use complex filter while using Retrieve function on Data Extension object

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to use the retrieve function with a complex filter. I am using this in a SSJS function in a cloud page. This is not working.
Would like to know if anyone has used something similar.

My end goal is to retrieve the details for a set of data extensions based on a complex filter.

```
var deDetail=DataExtension.Retrieve({
        LeftOperand: {
            Property: "CreatedDate",
            SimpleOperator: "greaterThanOrEqual",
            Value: "2018-08-27T00:00:00.000"
        },
        LogicalOperator: "AND",
        RightOperator: {
            Property: "CategoryID",
            SimpleOperator: "notEquals",
            Value: "9958"
        }});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's just a simple typo: `RightOperator` should be `RightOperand` (I tested your code after that tiny correction on my end and it worked).

Comment: Thanks a ton! Will give it a try.